# How to put multiple TextView sequentially programmatically in kotlin android?

Tags: android, view, textview, sequential

I want to make a page full of textViews. Every textView will have different value/text. I can achieve this by providing new object of every TextView.

[image: Like this one]

Please see the attached images in the google drive..

But my requirement is;
the second textView's first ('Lorem') word should start at the end of first textView's last ('Ipsum') word. It should look like they are single textView but they are not.

I am providing a similar app's screenshot with UI AUTOMATOR VIEWER uix file for better understanding.

The uix file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JIN5FYdYJ5SJtCgBMZaFqgL03dopdyeX/view?usp=share_link

[image: Similar App's Screenshot]

I tried it in a different ways.
I tried with multiple textViews to match each other.
I tried with different root layout; like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout
Non of my effort worked.

I was expecting is there any function that can get the every textViews first word position and last word position so that i can place my second textView at the first textView's last word position.
Or if there is a better way to do it; i am humble to know that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to merge text in same line or next line

Comment: merge the next textView's text in the same line

Comment: I think this cant be done with multiple text view you have to used single text view with HTML tags

Comment: Any tutorial or code might help

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement

> It should look like they are single textView but they are not.

Concatenating two textviews together usually yields bad results in my experience.

You could achieve something like this programatically by adding a LinearLayout container with horizontal orientation every time you want to concatenate two textviews.

Here is some example xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some long text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/concat_text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Begining of concat text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" End of concat text with a long text that enters a new line" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Another long text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But you would run into a problem when handling the new line of the second textview.

See this [image](https://postimg.cc/yW8CGHf4)

I would advice to merge both texts into a single textview and use spans in order to add styling to the merged text.
If this is not possible then please provide some information about why so I can provide a better answer.

Comment: Please see the sample apps from google play.. I just want to do the same..

I am providing two apps link:
App No-1
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pakdata.QuranMajeed

App No-2
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quran.labs.androidquran

if you can tell me what exactly they did in their app; how they implement the different text, and make every text clickable, then i might do the same..

Thank You

Comment: I sorry but I don't think I fully understand the functionality that you are looking to implement. You want this concatenated text to be clickable and that's why you want to have them in different textviews? if so I would recommend using a [ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan). There are many types of spans that can also add different types of styling and they can be added together.